# How to get the part of HashMap object?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

For example I have:

```
aaa 1
ccc 1
bbb 1
ddd 3
```

I need to assign a value to new HashMap object first three rows only, without the last row. How to do this?
Input HashMap object represented as >String, Integer<
Output HashMap object must be:

```
aaa 1
ccc 1
bbb 1
```

Comment: please clarify... as it is, this makes no sense whatsoever. perhaps tell us what your expected input and output is. why you are using a hashmap. what the key and value of the hashmap are. etc.

Comment: First of all, your question is too vague. Hardly comprehensible! And next, did you attempt anything to solve your problem?

Comment: To assign values within `HashMap` object you use `put`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)

Comment: His problem is that he's trying to do something based on the order of elements, not that he doesn't understand put(k, v).  Choosing the right data structures is kind of a big deal in programming, and I think he thinks HashMap does something that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashMap is unordered by definition.  LinkedHashMap is ordered, but based strictly on insert order.

You need to find a better data structure if you want to be able to replace by index, or you'll have to come up with, say, an array list that holds a copy of the keys which you can then use to handle the order.  Or if you don't really rely on the keys for anything, just use the array list directly.

Comment: If with HashMap it's impossible, then what type it's possible? How to do it? The most important is that I could to convert types.

Comment: Well, I posted an alternative for you in the answer.  You might want to look past the first sentence of the answer and you'll find some ideas there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do.  I'm going to assume that you start with a HashMap that looks like the first example and want to get a second hashmap that looks like the second example.  If this isn't what you want, please edit your question to be more clear.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> secondHashMap = firstHashMap.clone();
secondHashMap.remove("ddd");
```

Comment: The main idea - it's sorting with two parameters - by value. Then by key.
In my example output result should be 
aaa 1
bbb 1
ccc 1
ddd 3
I have easy sorting methods: or by key, or by value. And I don't know how to do It.